# Checking a value across multiple arrays

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a context property named 'flights'. I want to check if there is no value for this property, then go to the 'Iteration' test step, else set the first value of the property as a test case property.

Now what I want to do is perform a compare using this test case property value with a couple of arrays. Below is the scenario;

Check if value is in the villas array, if so +1 to VillasCount, else check in hotels array, if in there then +1 to beachCount else +1 to noCount.

Code is below:

```
// define properties required for the script to run. 
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) 
def dataFolder = groovyUtils.projectPath
    //Define an empty array list to load data from datasheet 
def dataTable_properties = [];


int villasCount = context.getProperty("villasCount")

def lines = new File(dataFolder + "/Test.csv").readLines()
def villas = []
lines.eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    if (index) {
        def data = line.split(',')*.trim()
        if (data[0]) villas << data[0]
    }
}

log.info "Villas : ${villas}"

context.setProperty("villasCount", villasCount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
for(f in flights){
    if(villas.contains(f)){
        villasCount = villasCount + 1
    }
}
```

Not 100% sure what you needed to compare, but you could easily expand this to check whatever you wanted.
If this is way off please provide more information on what you were trying to compare.